# something confused with docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx, docker

I'm trying to use docker for my project these days, but I'm confused with some problem with it.

My project created by nodejs + mongodb + nginx, now I want to publish my project using docker. I don't know whether I should use a node image + a mongodb image + a nginx image and then link them together or I should use a basic image like centos  and install node,mongo,nginx then run my server.

And another question, If I try the second way, in my dockerfile I run node server, it need to connect the mongodb use a correct user, but the mongodb   doesn't have user authorization config yet when node server runs, so the node server can't run, so how to create a user in Docker file?

Comment: First question, use 3 different containers. Second question, orchestrate the mongo container so it comes up first using `docker-compose`.

Comment: why it's better to use the first way?

Comment: Idiomatic Docker / microservices approach. One process (/ concern), one container. For more info: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#each-container-should-have-only-one-concern

Comment: @johnharris85 When I run mongodb image with --auth then I try to add a user , it's  not authorized, so how to add a user ?